# Make child element 100% height of the BODY element which is also 100%

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make the `<body>` element take up *at least* 100% height of the browser window but also expand to any content. I'm also trying to make its only `<div>` child element take up 100% of the `<body>` height as well.

**Illustration**

This is what is currently happening; Case A is the problem, Case B works as expected.

[image: Example of what's happening]

In Case A, the `div.page-content` (red box) should expand to the `body` (blue box), but it does not.

**Code**

Here's what I have.

**CSS**

```
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  min-height: 100%;
  padding-top: 57px;
}

.page-content {
  height: 100%;
}
```

**Html**

```
<html>
  <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top"></nav>
    <div class="page-content">
      <div class="page-container"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Note that the `nav` element is statically positioned and thus doesn't affect layout.

Body doesn't have a `height` specified because I want to height to be `auto` so it stretches to the content, but I don't want the height to be less than the browser window.

Body behaves as expected, it's the `div.page-content` that is only sizing to its own contents instead of stretching to the height of the `body`.

Is there a way to achieve the desired behavior without using javascript?

Comment: keep `body` to `height: 100%;`

Comment: ^ AKA change `min-height` in `body` to `height`.

Comment: no too sure what you look for, maybe moving overflow down to body ? http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/LNgLjW

Comment: @GCyrillus How are you not sure what I want? Right below the IMAGE I made in paint to illustrate the scenarios, I have a description of what I want to happen in Case A.

Comment: i meant behavior when it overflows ...(border, background, where body  / html stands. if nothing specific, then just classic inherits of 100% height from html is the basic way and answer :) ) min-height on body does not give the inheritance for height for the div

Comment: @Mr.Alien As stated, I cannot set a height on the body like `height: 100%`, because the body will then always be the height of the browser window instead of matching the content.

Comment: so body direct child cannot inherit any value to calculate % heights :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add `overflow:visible;` to `body`,  change `min-height:100%;` to  `height:100%;` for  `body` and  `height:100%;` to  `min-height:100%;` for `.page-content`

Comment: While this solution causes Case B to fail, in that the body doesn't extend to meet the content (because of `height: 100%` on the body), I'm accepting it because it generally worked for my purposes. I really just wanted the `div.page-content` to size properly; body can do whatever. Using `min-height: 100%` on `.page-content` was the trick, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

skip `page-content` and use `body` as the main container, so you skip the inheritance trouble your are facing.

example

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box
}
html {
  padding-top: 50px;
  height: 100%;
  background: white;
}
body {
  min-height: 100%;
  background: turquoise;
  margin: 0 2em;
  border:solid; /* see me */
}
nav {
  position: fixed;
  height: 50px;
  top: 0;
  left: 2em;
  right: 2em;
  background: tomato;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top"></nav>
<div class="page-container"></div>
```